# does cpu core count matter for code compiling?

Tags: compilation, cpu, hardware

I'm about to buy a laptop specifically for software development and want to be sure I don't end up with something I'm unhappy with, as I have experienced the pain of waiting 2+ minutes when compiling code on an old i3 laptop.

I'm looking at something with an i7-7500u cpu and 256GB ssd which I thought would do the job admirably, but then I saw that the cpu only has 2 cores / 4 threads.
 (https://www.intel.co.uk/content/www/uk/en/products/processors/core/i7-processors/i7-7500u.html)

Is compiling (C# MVC web application)  mainly based on single thread performance or is it likely that I'll see significant improvement spending a bit more and going for a 4 core / 8 thread cpu?

Comment: I compile C and C++ with VisualStudio now and then. Yes, it does appear to use all threads of my work machine's CPU. In addition, basic everyday apps like Chrome and Firefox are built to be multi-threaded, so getting more cores/threads makes sense. Depends on how long you want this machine to last and how big your code is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the compiler would schedule all the CPU threads to build the program then it matters. If not, then I think there is not much benefit in increasing the CPU core/thread number.
I think you may check the CPU usage when you compile the program and check if the usage of CPU is high enough. If it is below 50%, then I think it only uses one or two CPU thread to build the program, and increasing CPU core/thread count will not give you much benefit.

Also, if you use the hdd, not the ssd in your old laptop, then I think the bottleneck of the performance would probably be the read/write to disk drive, not the CPU. The usage of ssd would help a lot to improve the performance.